# How to get transforms/vector3s to display in editor as a moveable thing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i'm currently for a project trying to create some moving platforms and walls

I remembered a few years back I was going through this tutorial [The Explorer: 3D Game Kit - Tutorial - Quick Start](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/quick-start?uv=2019.4&courseId=5c616a81edbc2a0021b1bd11&projectId=5c514897edbc2a001fd5bdd0#) from the unity website

the first steps of the tutorial it has you spawn in a platform and select its path using two transform arrows like so
[image: Image from the tutorial website of said arrows]

I have downloaded the tutorial files again into a new project and had a look at the scripts but I cannot for the life of me figure out how it works, the two transform arrows are not game objects they only show when you click the top level of the platform pre-fab and are directly linked to two vector3s in the script I tried finding mentions of gizmos in the scripts and found little that appeared to be the solution

basically: how do I get the transform/vector3 arrows (what are those actually called?) to show up like they do in the tutorial or should I make the script use two empty game objects to set the start/end of travel

Comment: Those are called [`Handles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.html) but it is pretty unclear to me whether you want these in the editor or on runtime?

Comment: in the editor, in the tutorial you can drag them around the 3D game world when in edit mode to set the path of the platform when the game is running